# Make XCTAssertions accept function return values as arguments

Tags: swift, xctest

In Swift, when someone is using XCTest assertions, they can write an assertion like this:

```
XCTAssertTrue(foo.sameAs(bar), "\(foo) is not equal to \(bar)")
```

This allows for additional context, when the assertion fails to let someone know more about why things failed.

Further more something like this:

```
func printText(shouldPrint: BooleanType, text: String) {
    if shouldPrint {
        println("\(text)")
    }
}

func textData() -> (BooleanType, String) {
    return (true, "This is a test.")
}

printText(textData())
```

Will compile and run successfully printing out "This is a test". However, the following:

```
XCTAssertFalse(textData())
```

produces the compilation error: type '(BooleanType, String)' does not conform to protocol 'BooleanType'

What is the reason for the error, and what, if anything, can be done so the assertion will accept the return values from a function as its arguments?

Answer (score 1):

`XCTAssertFalse` expects a boolean argument, in this case you're passing in a tuple `(Boolean, String)`  In this specific case, try extracting the boolean element:

```
XCTAssertFalse(testData().0)
```

It works in the `printText` because swift automatically unpacks tuples into function parameters as long as the types match.

Comment: Strike that, I'm going to guess it's because `XCTAssertFalse(condition, format...)`  ie., it's a variadic function, so the args can't be reliably unpacked.